# How To find the memory leak?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, memory-leak

Im preparing a web-server and have already installed Wordpress on it. Everything worked fine. But instantly, the memory usage went up. Now I only have 300MB of memory free. To check the problem, I disabled some services like php, nginx, fail2ban, psad and mysql. It reduced the memory usage by a small amount but still its too high.

Then I restarted the machine and started working again. Again after some time, the memory usage shot up! How can I locate the exact problem? What might be causing this issue?

PS : Its an Ubuntu

PS : It looks like the swap is not yet used. Swap usage : 0 (The server is a virtual machine (KVM))

The output of free -m

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2003       1764        238          0         43       1350
-/+ buffers/cache:        370       1633
Swap:         2043          0       2043
```

Comment: If you want memory to stay free, don't assign it to a virtual machine!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your memory usage is fine. You have 1633 MB useable of 2003 MB (the `free` section in the second line, where buffers are considered), 1350 MB is used up by buffers. Please read [this site](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/) for an explanation.